# Inkscape: How can I access control points of corner/end nodes?

Tags: vector, inkscape

When drawing Bezier Curves how can I access control handles of corner/end nodes?

For corner nodes there seems to be a work around: Make the corner node smooth and then again make it a corner node.

But for end nodes there seems to be no way of controling the curve.

Why is that? Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put your cursor on the path near the end node (not on the node, but on the path). Grab the path and drag it in any direction, just slightly. A handle will pop out of the end node to re-shape the path in the direction you drag.

To return the end node to its state before this operation, grab the handle and drag it back to exactly where the node is.

Comment: This makes things more clear. So the default setting for control handles of corner nodes are exactly at the node. That's why the "work around" works, I guess... Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Just press Shift and drag out a handle